# 「僕がついてればいいんですけど。いそがしいもんでね。」はどういう意味ですか？

Tags: conditionals, contractions

「僕がついてればいいんですけど。いそがしいもんでね。」 はどういう意味ですか?
「ついてればいい」は辞書を調べてもまだよく分かりません。T。T

Answer (score 3):

> 僕がついてればいいんですけど。いそがしいもんでね。

ついてれば is a contracted form of ついて**い**れば. (dropping い)

The ついて (dictionary form [付]{つ}く) here means "to accompany~", "to be with~".

「～ていればいい」, consisting of the te-form verb + いれ(仮定形 of subsidiary verb 居る) + ば(conjunctive particle) + いい(良い), means "It's good if ~~" "It'd be better if ~~" or "I wish ~~ could ~~", etc.

> I wish I could be with you. (But I can't) because I'm busy, you know.